Javascript ARC drawing on canvas every timer update
I am working to create ARC moving animation.
For that I am trying to clear a canvas & draw arc on canvas every timer interval.
But i am failing in first step, Why arc is not drawing ?
HTML code :--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"/>
  <title>Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/page_style.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/cluster_app.js"></script>
 </head>
<body onload="doc_onload()">
            
    <div class="Screen_1" >   
        <canvas id="canvas_red_arc" width="448" height="448"></canvas>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>

JS code :--
unction myTimer()
{

    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_red_arc");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    // line color
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.stroke();
    //alert('Hello');

}


function doc_onload() 
{

    setInterval(myTimer, 150);
}

Even I tried to draw arc only once, its failing :---
var canvas;
var ctx;
var onetime_trigger=1;

function myTimer()
{
    if(onetime_trigger)
    {

        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_red_arc");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    
        ctx.lineWidth = 15;
        // line color
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.stroke();
        alert('Hello');
        onetime_trigger = 0;
    }

}

Edit :--
Seems to be blending issue, why the canvas image is coming so light ? I have kept the canvas at the bottom of the HTML page so it shall be displayed on the top of other images .. :--


Can you be more specific about what you expect the code to do? You clear the canvas then immediately draw the circle. Do you want some time to expire between clearing the canvas and drawing the circle?

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  .. even if i comment this method ... drawing not hapenning

Even I tried just to create ARC once its failing.. I checked no issue in code .. by ctr+shift+i

The issue must be elsewhere, because your code works for me. Please create a [mre].

I edited the post ....
Seems to be blending issue, why the canvas image is coming so light ? I have kept the canvas at the bottom of the HTML page so it shall be displayed on the top of other images..

I want this canvas arc to be displayed on the top .... and below it will be few images....

Like I am drawing RED arc on top of white circle images .. and below the line marker images ..... in this video ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9GEG_DiVCo

You still haven't created a [mre] that reproduces the issue. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/78sxk4zg/

What I found canvas is always placed at location (0, 0) of the html page... Is it possible to place the position of canvas any where in html page..? I tried left and top both... Online in html.. But no affect. But you applying to class top and left property
